# How can I produce many time stamps that increment by 1 minute in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program that reads in IRC posts and then determines the activity of that channel. Activity would be measured in two ways:

1. Posts per hour
2. Change in activity from last time step

The way i want to do it is to create a dictionary of lists. The keys in the dictionary will be a time stamp and will increase by exactly one minute. I will then scan over all lines in the IRC log and add the posts to the appropriate keys given the time and date the post was written. Thus allowing me no find out how many posts per minute (and therefore hours, days etc) were written.

Here is a sample of the log

```
'[2015-04-22 08:57:36] <Sirisian> ['
```

And the beginning of my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

in_file = open('Output.txt')

with in_file as f: 
    data = f.readlines()

#create dictionary of one minute timestamps 
start = '[2015-04-22 08:57:00]'
min_store = {}

#check time stamp of post and asign to correct key
```

How can a code something that takes this [2015-04-22 08:57:00] and returns many time stamps, all with 1 minute increments up to some time many days / months in the future ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at datetime.timedelta. You can parse your log datestamps into datetime objects which are much more workable. You can then just add and subtract datetime.timedelta objects from them to get times into the past or the future. datetime objects are also hashable so you can use them as dictionary keys directly, and can parse dates and times from strings so you can load in your log doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be just adding posts to this dictionary as you see them rather than guessing at the time the log file ends. This will make your script reusable. You also seem to misunderstand how to open a file. You should also use the `datetime` module to handle the timestamps. Here is an example:

```
import datetime
import re

my_dict = {}
with open('Output.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        stamp = re.search('\[(.+)\]', line)
        stamp = stamp.group(1)
        d = datetime.strptime(stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s')
        d.seconds = 0
        msg = # here is where the message would go. you need to parse it out
        if d in my_dict:
            my_dict[d].append(msg)
        else:
            my_dict[d] = [msg]
```

Play with that and you should have a reusable script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that uses the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html) library:

```
from collections import Counter
import time
cnt = Counter()

date_input_format = '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'
date_output_format = '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00]'
start = time.strptime('[2015-04-22 09:01:00]', date_input_format)

with open('Output.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    line_date = time.strptime(line[:21], date_input_format)
    if line_date > start:
      cnt[time.strftime(date_output_format, line_date)] += 1
#Sort the keys for presentation
moments = cnt.keys()
#Keep track of how much has changed from minute to minute
previous = 0
for moment in sorted(moments):
  current = cnt[moment]
  print(moment, current, '{0:{1}}'.format((current - previous), '+' if (current - previous) else ''))
  previous = current
```

With a `Output.txt` that looks like this:

```
[2015-04-22 08:57:36] Hi
[2015-04-22 08:57:45] Yo
[2015-04-22 08:58:36] Hey
[2015-04-22 08:58:37] Ho
[2015-04-22 09:01:36] Let's
[2015-04-22 09:57:16] Go
[2015-04-22 09:57:26] Good bye
[2015-04-22 09:58:36] See Ya
[2015-04-22 09:59:36] Peace
```

You should see the following output:

```
[2015-04-22 09:01:00] 1 +1
[2015-04-22 09:57:00] 2 +1
[2015-04-22 09:58:00] 1 -1
[2015-04-22 09:59:00] 1 0
```